Interceptor not working in Angular 18 project
I'm trying to use my interceptor but is not working. The console log isnot shown so, I don't know why, my interceptor is not active.
What i'm doing bad?
auth.interceptor.ts
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authService:AuthService) {

    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        var authReq = req;
        console.log("intercepting");
        const token = this.authService.getToken();
        if(token != null) {
            authReq = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
            });
        }
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }
}

export const authInterceptorProviders =
    {
      provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass : AuthInterceptor,
      multi : true
    }

app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http';
import { authInterceptorProviders } from './services/auth/auth.interceptor';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), 
    provideRouter(routes), 
    provideAnimationsAsync(), 
    provideHttpClient(),
    authInterceptorProviders
  ]
};

Thanks for your help!

have you perhaps imported the HttpClientModule multiple times across different modules?

Can you create a minimal reproducible example, perhaps on Stackblitz, so I could test it out locally. I have a few things in mind

check arguments of provideHttpClient. with standalone api it is a bit different. you either provide interceptor function or provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())

@T.Jami it is a login with a form that you can insert username and pass. When you click button, i'm able to get token from WS and save into localstorage. But later, when I try a request, I receive empty header, like if the intercetpro was not working, and it's not working beacuse i can't see logs. /
I don't have  HttpClientModule, i'm importing HttpClient. Module is deprecated

It seems that I have active interceptor doing changes, but in my cakend the header is null. I'm angry because in console I can see the header ok, what is happening?
